# API to get all OVM component handles

Tags: system-verilog, methodology, uvm

Is there an API to get all OVM component handles in a verification environement? The reason why I am asking is, I need to convert down OVM_FATAL to OVM_NOPRINT using OVM report handler. This report handler is an object instantiated in each ovm_component. Currently I have set_report_severity_action_hier(OVM_FATAL, OVM_NO_ACTION) called from base_test which just applies to the test. I need to have this affect all the components like monitor and driver.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a ovm_component::find_all() method, but that has the same issue as set_report_severity_action_hier(); you need to call it after all the components have been built. The OVM does not have a phase_ready_to_end() callback, so you need to put the call to set_report_severity_action_hier() in any phase after the build in your base test.

Comment: Thanks Dave. find_all is not a static function and it is a part of ovm_root. so shouldnt I use ovm_top.find_all? Also can you give me any usage of it? I tried doing this in my base testcase. ovm_top.find_all(get_name(), components). It just gave me back ovm_test_top component handle

Comment: OK got it. I used the fact that ovm_is_match supports regular expression. So I used ovm_root.find_all("*", components). Thanks Dave for your solution